# Cast exception of nested class in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am having issues getting the query right for a nested class, after playing around with the code and checking examples I ended up with the below.

The basic XML is

```
<Connections>
 <Connection>
  <ConnectionName>CConnect</ConnectionName>
  <SiteA SiteName="Site1" IP="000">Site1info</SiteA>
  <SiteB SiteName="Site2" IP="000">Site2info</SiteB>
 </Connection>
</Connections>
```

The LINQ query outputting to list

```
List<ConnectionItem> NewConnectionList = xDoc.Root.Elements("Connection")
            .Select(q => new ConnectionItem
            {
                ID = (string)q.Element("ID"),
                ConnectionName = (string)q.Element("ConnectionName"),
                TypeList = (string)q.Element("TypeList"),
                SiteA = (SiteDetails)q.Elements("SiteA").Select(s => new SiteDetails { SiteName = (string)q.Attribute("SiteName"), Router = (string)q.Attribute("Router"), IP = (string)q.Attribute("IP") }),
                SiteB = (SiteDetails)q.Elements("SiteB").Select(s => new SiteDetails { SiteName = (string)q.Attribute("SiteName"), Router = (string)q.Attribute("Router"), IP = (string)q.Attribute("IP") })
            }).ToList();
```

SiteA and SiteB appears to be the issue, it is a subclass call **SiteDetails** in class **ConnectionItem**. The compiler shows no issue with the query, however at run time I catch the error with casting to SiteDetails.

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,Piccolo_Test.SiteDetails]' to type 'Piccolo_Test.SiteDetails'.
>
> at Piccolo_Test.frmMain.b__c(XElement q) in c:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test\Forms\frmMain.cs:line 493
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>
> at Piccolo_Test.frmMain.readXML() in c:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test\Forms\frmMain.cs:line 492

Is this an issue with the lambda expression or am I casting the subclass incorrectly?

Comment: [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) return collection, if you want one object use [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549039(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb535118(v=vs.100).aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549274(v=vs.100).aspx) instead

Comment: `Elements("SiteA").Select(..)` returns an `IEnumerable<SiteDetails>`. Change to `Elements("SiteA").Select(..).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: You're probably going to have issues with `SiteA` and `SiteB` being completely empty considering you're referencing `q` when getting attribute values. `q` is the `Connection` element and has no attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the guys in the comments above I got it working.

As @Mathew and @Grundy mentioned, i needed .FirstOrDefault() at the end line, which then ran without error and outputted to the list the main part except the SiteDetails values were null. Then as pointed out @Ichabod I was incorrectly referring to the outer expressions lambda value "r" instead of "s".

```
SiteA = (SiteDetails)q.Elements("SiteA").Select(s => new SiteDetails { SiteName = (string)s.Attribute("SiteName"), Router = (string)s.Attribute("Router"), IP = (string)s.Attribute("IP") }).FirstOrDefault()
```